# iPhone Login Screen that shows a Table View after logging in the user

Tags: iphone, macos, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a navigation based template application, I parse data into table view.
I want to put a login screen before parse the data. I did the login screen and and succeed the login check.
My problem is that when the user presses the button I change the view to the tableview.
what a way should I draw? I want to learn how can i close the tableview screen when the app launched and after pressed the button I want to show the tableview.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a navigation based template, you could simply push another view on the stack, or you could have the second table view as the first screen, and push the login over the top.  pressing on a button to login will pop the login screen off the stack to reveal the main tableview screen.

I have put the login details in the user preferences screen.

Comment: i understand the logic but i don't know which code i will use can you write the codes ?